# Universal Link open only base URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links

is it possible to set a path in the "paths" array inside the apple-app-site-association file that will open only the original domain in the application?

for example, 
if my domain is 
https://www.example.com

i want the app to be opened if a user clicks a link to
https://www.example.com

but not to 
https://www.example.com/a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test solutions below, so I can't guarantee that they will work. At the same time they all are based on [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html?utm_source=revxblog), so they should. I currently don't want to invest time into setting up test environment for this, so that would be nice if you share your test results.

My first suggestion would be just this:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "%YOUR.APP.ID%",
        "paths": [
             "/"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

If this didn't help, here's another go:

```
{
  "applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
      {
        "appID": "%YOUR.APP.ID%",
        "paths": [
             "NOT /?*",
             "/*"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Here `?` matches any single character, and `*` matches any substring, including empty. The idea in the second case is that the system might use the rules from top to bottom.

> Because the system evaluates each path in the paths array in the order it is specified—and stops evaluating when a positive or negative match is found—you should specify high priority paths before low priority paths. 
>   https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html?utm_source=revxblog

The third idea would be to at first exclude all the top level components you know then adding allow all. That might be really overwhelming, especially if you don't control paths or they change.

Comment: Not certain, but I think the OP wants to exclude any path off of the base URL, not just single chars.

Comment: @danh in my understanding "NOT /?*" will exclude everything that is at least single character (as opposed to * to be anything, including empty string)

Comment: I'd answer myself if I knew the answer, but I'm confused by this one: are you suggesting three alternatives that you know to be working, or suggesting three things to try in hopes that one of them works?

Comment: @danh I'm suggesting three alternatives that I *think* should work. I didn't try those, because my use cases were different, but I have several apps in the store with Universal Links support that I've implemented myself so I have some relevant experience. You can read supplied documentation and see that solutions are based on what's found there. The only thing that prevents me from putting my word on those suggestions is that I haven't tried (exactly) them myself and it is not as easy to try.

Comment: Agree... it's one of those cases where it doesn't make sense to setup a rig to prove something if you don't have one already running. It might be worthwhile to make clear that you've proposed several correct, untested alternatives.